# How Do I Setup SublimeREPL with Anaconda's interpreter?

Tags: python, sublimetext, anaconda

I love Python in Sublimetext, but what I really need is an interactive mode for data exploration. However, for the life of me I cannot get SublimeREPL to use Anaconda's interpreter. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I have added the following to my SublimeREPL.settings.user file, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "Users/anton/anaconda/envs/py3k/bin/python3:{PATH}"}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `Packages/User` folder, create `SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` with the following contents:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "caption": "Python",
                    "id": "Python",

                    "children":[
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "Python - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-i", "-u"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "IPython - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "autocomplete_server": true,
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {
                                    "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                                    "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

In the `"cmd"` lines, change `/path/to/Anaconda/python` with the actual path to your python executable you want to use. If you're on Windows, either use a single `/` as path delimiter, or double `\\`:

```
c:/Anaconda/bin/python.exe
# or
c:\\Anaconda\\bin\\python.exe
```

Save the file, and you should now have `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python - Anaconda` and `IPython - Anaconda` menu options to start REPLs with the Anaconda interpreter. If you have multiple versions of Python installed (for example, 2.7 and 3.3) you can just duplicate the `children` contents and alter the `caption` and `cmd` paths appropriately.

Comment: It works well for me on sublime text 3. Is there any way to add my new interpreter to the command palette?

Comment: @user2265478: in the folder, where the "Main.sublime-menu" file you added a new section to is, there's also a "Default.sublime-commands" file. You have to add a corresponding section there (take care of a proper "id" parameter)

Answer (score 7):

With the caveat that this is an old question with an accepted answer that makes your problem go away, it doesn't directly answer your question. (I would have made this a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation.)

The reason your user settings line doesn't work is because you're specifying the path incorrectly. You are not including a slash before `Users`, so it's a relative path and not absolute, and you are also giving the full path to the Python binary, not the directory containing the binary. Rewriting what you have to:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/Users/anton/anaconda/envs/py3k/bin:{PATH}"}
}
```

should solve your problem. Furthermore, I believe it is best practice to copy the contents of the Default SublimeREPL settings file to the user settings file, and then to add the `default_extend_env` line at the end.

Comment: thanks, i want to add my R installed from conda and the accepted answer looks really convoluted to me so i will try this instead - thanks again ;)

Comment: it works! :) i had to use full path as tilda expansion didn't work for some reason but with full path it works flawlessly - thanks a ton!