# Set working directory to location of active script in SublimeREPL

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I use Sublime Text 3 with SublimeREPL for my commands in both R and Python. Whenever SublimeREPL is booted up, it has the present working directory set to the Sublime Text installation directory. This occurs on both Windows and Mac OSX. Often, I need to run code from R or Python which opens a file that is located in the same folder as the `R` or `py` file that I'm running. Under normal circumstances (i.e. not using Sublime Text), this works fine, as the R or Python interpreter knows to look in the same directory as the script is located.

However, with SublimeREPL, commands are 'transferred' as text to the SublimeREPL, so SublimeREPL has no idea where the program came from. As a result, I need to explicitly specify the location of the file I am trying to access in each of my programs, which is a little unwieldy, especially if my programs move around (which they do).

Is there some way of making SublimeREPL set the present working directory, on bootup, to the same directory as the currently active script file? This would be a fine workaround, as it would simply mean having to restart the REPL if I changed to using a file located in a different directory.

[image]

Comment: I've installed a clean version of SublimeText3 and SublimeREPL in ubuntu just now, and when I start the SublimeREPL, and write `import os; os.getcwd()` it correctly shows my current file directory. So in other words I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861176/how-do-i-setup-sublimerepl-with-anacondas-interpreter).

For Python and IPython, in your `Packages/User` folder, create    `SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`, where you specify `"cwd": "$file_path"`    :

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "caption": "Python",
                    "id": "Python",

                    "children":[
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "Python - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-i", "-u"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "IPython - Anaconda",
                            "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "autocomplete_server": true,
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/Anaconda/python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {
                                    "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                                    "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I guess, for R it is the same.

Comment: Please don't copy and paste from other answers, even if you link to them. If an answer solves another question, you should flag that question as a duplicate, or at the very least leave the link to the relevant answer in a comment.

Comment: What worked for me was not "cwd": "$file_path" as proposed in the answer above but "cwd": "$folder". You can find a detailed description of my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077749/why-sublimerepl-wont-import-a-python-module-or-read-a-file-in-cwd