# Why SublimeREPL won't import a Python module or read a file in CWD?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm using **Sublime Text 3** build 3126 on **Ubuntu Zesty** with the **SublimeREPL** plugin.

I open a Python REPL with *CTRL+SHIFT+P* >> *SublimeREPL: Python* and send a file to REPL with *CTRL+, , F* and evertyhing works as long as I work on a single Python script file. As soon as I try to move some parts of my code to another module and import it in the main file, I get the nasty ***ImportError: No module named*** error.

Trying to open a text file located in the same directory with:

```
codecs.open('filename', encoding='utf-8')
```

results in:

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you investigate whether there was a relation between the file/panel from where you opened *SublimeREPL: Python* and the output of `print os.getcwd()`? SublimeREPL initializes its cwd at its startup of the REPL. The cwd will stay for the entire lifetime of the REPL.

As you pointed out, the default cwd for *SublimeREPL: Python* is:

```
"cwd": "$file_path"
```

This means that starting *SublimeREPL: Python* with your cursor in a blank Sublime panel, results in `/opt/sublime_text/` as the cwd. This could be considered undesired and confusing.

However, if you start *SublimeREPL: Python* while your cursor is in the .py file that you want to run, the REPL will use **the folder of your current .py file** as its cwd.

Personally I think this is the desired behaviour, but you have to know it before it becomes convenient.

If you change the settings for the cwd to:

```
"cwd": "$folder",
```

the above behaviour of the stays unchanged for cases where you're not using sublime-projects. When you do use a sublime-project, the python REPL cwd will be the main project folder, independent of the cursor location at REPL startup. This might be the desired behaviour if you have a python-driven project. However, if you are just using some python scripts in a bigger project, you probably don't want your main project folder to be the cwd in the python REPL.

Comment: Can confirm. As it turns out I had a habit of opening a REPL while having a cursor in an empty REPL plane. Gosh, how I hate these things. There's no mention of this behavior in the docs and I commend every genius that's able to notice it all depends on where the damned cursor is happening to be. I see the logic behind it but still think the "$folder" parameter would work better for the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a full day tearing my hair out while trying to find a solution to this problem.

First I thought there is some problem with $PYTHONPATH. I followed clues given in this (closed) issue on the SublimeREPL GitHub page: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/355

And while the solution given by the plugin's author didn't work, adding the *PYTHONPATH* variable containing a path to my working directory to the *extend_env* key in *Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu* solved the failing imports problem.

I thought I was golden, then I tried to read a text file in Python and got the IOError. Then it finally got to me that the wrong CWD (current working directory) was the culprit.

As the Python docs specify:

> "When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - **the directory containing the input script (or the current directory)**.
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
> - shell variable PATH). the installation-dependent default.

I tried *import os* and *print os.getcwd()* in the REPL promt and surely what I got was:

```
/opt/sublime_text/
```

So what I did? The solution was a simple change to a line in *Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu* (in a section corresponding to the REPL I was using). From:

```
"cwd": "$file_path",
```

to:

```
"cwd": "$folder",
```

Now calling *os.getcwd()* resulted in a path to the directory containing the file I sent to SublimeREPL and everything worked. Why *$file_path* gives *'/opt/sublime_text'* rather than the path to a file is either a question to the plugin's author or some underlying quirk with my system.