# How to make SublimeREPL recognize installed python modules?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have a python file that starts with:

```
import random
from numpy.random import choice
from decimal import *
```

When I run in IDLE, I don't get any import-related errors, but when I try to run the same file in SublimeREPL, it returns:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.random
```

I am new to using SublimeREPL and I have no idea why this is happening. If you need any information I haven't provided, just comment.

Comment: Is `numpy` installed for the interpreter Sublime is using?

Comment: How do I find out which interpreter is being used? I have two python installations, 2.7, and 3.4.2. I have numpy installed for 3.4.2.

Comment: Well does `print 'foo'` work in the REPL? If so, it's using 2.x. Look into e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20861176/3001761 for specifying a particular interpreter.

Comment: It is 2.x. How do I change it to the correct installation?

Comment: Well did you read the question I've already linked to about specifying a particular interpreter? Or read SublimeREPL's documentation?