# getting sublime text 3 to use anaconda python

Tags: python, linux, sublimetext3

So I've installed anaconda to a directory I have privileges for but I can't get sublime text 3 to recognise that the shell is now using anaconda python:

```
>which python
/local/home/USER/Apps/anaconda/bin/python
```

when I build with sublime launched from the same shell:

```
import astropy
print astropy.__file__
```

it gives a different directory: /soft/python-SL7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/**init**.pyc

My .tcshrc file reads:

```
setenv PATH /local/home/USER/Apps/anaconda/bin:${PATH}
alias subl /local/home/USER/Apps/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
```

My .bashrc (not that it should be using it) reads:

```
export PATH="/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to create a new [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) that points to your Anaconda installation. Create a new file in Sublime with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/local/home/USER/Apps/anaconda/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file in your `Packages/User` directory (should be `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`) as `Anaconda.sublime-build`. Finally, select **`Tools → Build System → Anaconda`**, and when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in a Python file it should now run using Anaconda.

If you want to set up [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) to use Anaconda with IPython in Sublime, you can follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861527/1426065) to set up the proper menu option (altering the path to suit your environment, of course), and my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/6cb1dfbe8a124e1ca5af) for setting up SublimeREPL for IPython 4 and Jupyter.

Comment: That's not working for me. I copy-pasted your answer just to make sure. I've also replaced the cmd with `["which", "python"]` and `["which", "/local/home/USER/Apps/anaconda/bin/python"]. Both cmds return `/local/home/USER/Apps/anaconda/bin/python`.

So the shell is correct it just keeps importing from `/soft/python-SL7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Moreover, when I try `pip install astropy --update` it completes by saying it installed the previous version. Could this be related?

Comment: @Lucidnonsense as far as `pip` is concerned, what does `pip -V` return? It should tell you which python executable it's associated with. For the other issue, are you setting a `PYTHONPATH` variable in your `.tcshrc` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: I've managed to fix this somehow. I don't know how. (`pip -V` returns anaconda path).

Thanks

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Probably sublime does not invoke the command "conda activate base". How could we do that?

Comment: @kstn use the [`Conda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Conda) package.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but you can also have a per project setting by editing the project file and adding this:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
        "selector": "source.python",
        "shell_cmd": "\"python3\" -u \"$file\""
    }
],
```

This also has the advantage of not leaving too many build systems in the build menu.

Comment: This is entirely different. This is a build system automatically created by the [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) Sublime package, which is in no way related to the Anaconda Python distribution which the OP is using.