# How do I run python 3.5 in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have installed the python 3.5 interpretor in my device (Windows).

Can anybody guide me through the process of using packages to run it like `SublimeREPL`?

Comment: I think you may want to create a new [build system](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) for python3.5 on sublime text.  You may be able to copy the existing python build system and modify it for your use.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use any Python version you want to run programs from Sublime - you just need to define a new [build system](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). Select **`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System`**, then delete its contents and replace it with:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Python35/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

assuming that `C:/Python35/python.exe` is the correct path. If `python.exe` resides someplace else, just put in the correct path, using forward slashes `/` instead of the Windows standard backward slashes `\`.

Save the file as `Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build`, where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** - Sublime should already automatically save it in the right directory. Now, there will be a **`Tools -> Build System -> Python3`** option that you can select for running files with Python 3.

For details on setting up SublimeREPL with Python 3, please follow the instructions in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861527/1426065).

Comment: for unix, use `which python3` in terminal to get your python path to replace "C:/Python35/python.exe".

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed python3 and SublimeREPL, you can try setting up key bindings with the correct path to the python3 file.

```
[
     {
        "keys":["super+ctrl+r"],
        "command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python 3.6 - Open File",
                     "id": "repl_python",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["The directory to your python3.6 file", "-i", "$file"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
    }
]
```

You can try by copying this code into your /Sublime Text 3/Preferences/Key Bindings/

Hope this helps!