# Using different conda envs with Sublime REPL

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, anaconda, sublimerepl

I'm trying to set up Sublime Text 3 as a multilingual editor for doing data science.

For this I use Sublime REPL for executing code in Sublime, and intend to use Anaconda's (continuum analytics) built in virtual environments to make a venv for each project.

Unfortunately, the virtualenv option in Sublime REPL does not seem to support environments made with `conda create`.

By default it seems that Sublime REPL is using the root copy of python in anaconda, as it prints this information.

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 16:14:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However, even trying fixes proposed by other questions: 
[Sublime text3 and virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963030/sublime-text3-and-virtualenvs) and
[How Do I Setup SublimeREPL with Anaconda's interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861176/how-do-i-setup-sublimerepl-with-anacondas-interpreter) once things are set up I get an error

```
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

When I try to point at a virtual env created with `conda create`.

Is there any way to make Sublime REPL execute code with a particular conda environment? Or do I need to avoid the Anaconda distribution and use a manual install of python and `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 2):

This question might be a duplicate for [**this one**](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiftpb9nLnOAhXLJsAKHS4GDvYQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20861176%2Fhow-do-i-setup-sublimerepl-with-anacondas-interpreter&usg=AFQjCNFEXC7RBi6mfKxPjrqyE-WW2ZE76g).

As explained in the answer above, you can extend the list of usable python versions:

(Almost a) Quotation from the answer above:

In your Packages/User folder, create `SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` with the following contents:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "caption": "Python",
                    "id": "Python",

                    "children":[
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "Python - YourVirtualEnv",
                            "id": "repl_python",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/yourPythonVersion", "-i", "-u"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "IPython - YourVirtualEnv",
                            "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "autocomplete_server": true,
                                "cmd": ["/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/yourIPythonVersion", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                                "cwd": "$file_path",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "python",
                                "extend_env": {
                                    "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                                    "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

If you're on Windows, either use a single / as path delimiter, or double \:

```
c:/Anaconda/bin/python.exe
# or
c:\\Anaconda\\bin\\python.exe
```

Save the file, and you should now have `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python - Anaconda` and `IPython - Anaconda` menu options to start REPLs with the Anaconda interpreter.

**If you have multiple versions of Python installed (for example, 2.7
and 3.3) or multiple virtualenvs you can just duplicate the children contents and alter the
caption and cmd paths appropriately.**